# Why do some investors pay for real-time newswires when the news is likely priced-in by the time it is read?

Tags: investing, trading, news

I've noticed that some retail traders/investors subscribe to newswire services such as Dow Jones Newswires, Refinitiv/Reuters financial news, Benzinga Pro, etc. Institutional investors probably have better sources of news and they probably use computers to parse news articles in milliseconds, so I don't think retail traders/investors are able to trade on news, because the news is probably priced-in by the time it is read by a human. If financial news is most likely stale by the time they are manually read by retail traders/investors, what's the point in spending money on such news services?

Comment: You're still ahead of all those that haven't done that I suppose so if there's a stampede starting you might be trampled slightly less.

Comment: Also, if you pay for a time optimized high performance news feed you are getting the same data as institutional investors. And who says they read it manually? It is not like there are not a lot of smaller "retail" investors doing algorithmic trading and - news analysis.

Comment: @TomTom But wouldn't you have to read the news with your own eyes (which causes delay)?

Comment: Compared to what? And as I said - "retail" - I know a guy running a business doing options market making. Half a million USD in capital. THIS IS STILL RETAIL. He is not institutional by any rating.

Comment: Flux, there are no systems that magically read news in English, and then buy or sell based on that.

Comment: @Fattie are you sure? Many of simpler e-shops can already recommend you what to buy and sentiment analysis is one of the better explored parts of natural language processing. You dont have to understand what is sais or its impact on the economy if you know how the author feels about it.

Comment: @wondra - yes, I'm completely sure.  BTW it's trivial to ("instantly") get a feed of news articles that MENTION some topic.  (Anyone can do that.)  Flux's concept that "big" investors have systems that trade "instantly" based on news articles, is totally wrong.

Comment: @Fattie You are mistaken, the 'magic' is called natural language processing and is a well-established field of machine learning. Trades are absolutely triggered based off of automatic article parsing.

Comment: A more likely scenario is that the institutional quants have programmed the interpretation of price and volume change in a short time frame, resulting in automated trades. Not that I've paid much attention to them but I have come across web sites  that scan for large volume increases early in each session (pre, regular and after hours).

Comment: hi @BradyGilg , hmm, we work on NLP crap for a couple of large companies, and as far as I'm aware nothing like that is used by quants or other trading companies.  You may be mistaken, or, we are discussing slightly different things?  Note that: .. let's say there was some news "Tim Cook is deceased."  Let's say ***as humans*** you and I are on a desk, and we get that news.  Do we sell, or buy, APPL?  Even with something as clear-cut as "frost .. FCOJ futures!" do you sell or buy?  The scenario Flux describes just isn't coherent, it isn't a thing.

Comment: BTW the whole point of a great analysis desk is that they are on top of news or possible news way before the minimum-wage journalists at news services put out a story.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think retail traders/investors are able to trade on news, because the news is probably priced-in by the time it is read by a human.

Your assumption that it is all priced in is incorrect.  Not everything rises (or drops) with  the news release nor does price instantaneously gap up/down to its new price and then level out in the seconds after the news is released.  News isn't always binary.

I'm not going to chase around for looking for some spectacular examples so here's a more modest one that I observed this week.  Kohl's (KSS) made a positive news announcement Tuesday morning.  The stock rose 10% fairly quickly and then retraced a bit during the day.  For the next three days it gradually rose nearly another 20%.

So without the news, how would one know that there was an opportunity to invest or trade  this stock, which in this case, was profitable?

In addition, per your premise that institutional investors use computers to parse news articles in milliseconds, from Wednesday to Friday, where was their edge in this?